# How to organize sheet inventory data with variants in different rows to mixed data in same row of that specific product?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have a workbook with 2 sheets. In 1st sheet, I have all my items values in different rows along with variants, as shown below -

Input Sheet
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiTPA.png)

In 2nd sheet, all the values of variants combined in one main item, as shown bellow -

Desired Output Sheet
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcqKR.png)

I want to write a python code for doing this in google spreadsheet. Please help me.

Comment: hi, please share what you already tried to do, the goal of stack overflow is to help you, not do stuff for you :)

Comment: Thanks Ren for reviewing my question. I am not getting the way to proceed. I am totally blank. It's my kind request to please guide me with little overview of doing such task if possible.

Comment: I am not getting how to group different variant sku into one main sku (with different number of variants for each sku) and put values corresponding to it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.