# Google spreadsheet move data from different rows with same ID to same rows but different column

Tags: python, google-sheets

How to move the data from different rows with same ID in same rows but different column? For example, I have this table in sheet1

Input Sheet

[image]

Desired Output Sheet

[image]

Comment: In your situation, what language do you want to achieve your goal using? You want to use the bult-in formula or a script?

Comment: Built-in formula if possible, otherwise python script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to organize sheet inventory data with variants in different rows to mixed data in same row of that specific product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71465646/how-to-organize-sheet-inventory-data-with-variants-in-different-rows-to-mixed-da)